# Using subquery aggregation but output different

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

I wan to update the product unit price with margin of 15% when the quantity sold is more than 10 unit.

The dataset is https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1O7RAnfJMmqOPaiIwQyKSXKXVf01NpCJd?usp=sharing

This is my code

```
UPDATE PRODUCT_MASTER
SET Unit_Price = t1.new_price 
FROM PRODUCT_MASTER as pm
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      Product_ID,
      SUM(Unit_Sold) AS total_unit
    FROM SALES_TRANSACTION
    GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
) AS t2 
  ON pm.Product_ID = t2.Product_ID 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
       Product_ID,
       (Unit_Price * 1.15) AS new_price
    FROM Product_Master
) AS t1
  ON pm.Product_ID = t1.Product_ID 
WHERE t2.total_unit > 10

SELECT *  
FROM PRODUCT_MASTER
```

My output is

[image: subquery_output]

If I do a manual calculation for 201 since its total_unit is more than 10, 500*1.15 = 575 but the result display 760. This is same for other product_ID with more than 10 units sold such as 203-206).

Where is the mistake I have done?

Comment: Provide your dataset as textual formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO code, not as external link (or create online fiddle). Provide desired output for this data.

Comment: The syntax in your query is not valid in MySql. Tag the correct database that you use.

Comment: @forpas, I am using SSMS to run it so it is MySQL

Comment: No, it is SQL Server.

Comment: Oh, my bad. It should be TSQL. I have updated the tag.

Comment: Whitespace doesn't cost, you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, although it can be significantly simplified, returns correct results as you can see in this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=15415233d456cb557ae4c4bed01698da).

The only way that it could return the results that you get is if you ran it 3(!) consecutive times like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2dd512293dee2368f3a88a1258a58eb4).

Simplify your query to this:

```
UPDATE pm 
SET pm.Unit_Price = 1.15 * pm.Unit_Price
FROM PRODUCT_MASTER as pm
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Product_ID 
  FROM SALES_TRANSACTION 
  GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
  HAVING SUM(Unit_Sold) > 10
) AS t2 ON pm.Product_ID = t2.Product_ID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cbbf199d5e588a96df4644a13ba170b8).

Comment: when I run your code. The Unit_price for 201 and 203-206 is more than 15%. Are you getting the same result as mine?  

201 is 760, 
202 is 300, 
203 is 303, 
204 is 1520, 
205 is 1368   and 
206 is 1216

Comment: @popo In my answer I provided a demo (based on your sample data) where you can see that the results are correct.

Comment: @popo if you get 760 for 201 this means that you run the query 3 consecutive times. Are  you using the code as it is? Do you have any triggers defined?

Comment: I got the same response as yours. I put double select statement when I run. Thank you for your help.